# Trouble setting JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, maven

I have set JAVA_HOME as below from batch file, but it still pointing to what is installed in C drive

```
@echo on
set JAVA_HOME=D:\xxxx\JAVA\jdk1.7.0_80
set M2_HOME=D:\xxxx\JAVA\apache-maven-3.3.9
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
CMD
```

1. JAVA_HOME is set before path, so it should take preference over all
   other values in path.
2. Setting USER path variable appended JAVA_HOME at the end. Then appended
   value takes least preference. So didn't set USER path variable. Used
   batch file to update path.
3. I don't have admin access. Cant change anything in C drive. So
   java.exe, javaws.exe those files I cannot remove or modify. These
   files indirectly specify default JAVA_HOME.

Please let me know any other way to override default JAVA_HOME. I need to change JAVA_HOME for maven to use new JDK for compilation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast I found what is the issue. My JDK is corrupt or missing crucial jars.

System to pick up JAVA location and set it as JAVA_HOME, jdk should contain java.exe, javaw.exe, javaws.exe in bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this going to Control Panel/System/System Advanced Configuration/ then press the button "Environment Variables" and set JAVA_HOME in the user variables box

Comment: I mentioned why I am not using USER PATH, it appends at the end

Answer (score 0):

Try using the setx command.

> Set modifies the current shell's (window) environment values, and the
>   change is available immediately, but it is temporary. the change will
>   not affect other shells that are running, and as soon as you close the
>   shell, the new value is lost until such time as you run set again.
>
> setx modifies the value permenantly, which affects all future shells,
>   but does not modify the environment of the shells already running. you
>   have to exit the shell and reopen it before the change will be
>   available, but the value will remain modified until you change it
>   again.

Syntax for setx is : `setx variableName variableValue`

Source : [Difference between set and setx](https://superuser.com/questions/916649/what-is-the-difference-between-setx-and-set-in-environment-variables-in-windows)

Credit goes to [Frank Thomas](https://superuser.com/users/171793/frank-thomas)